# How to add a custom GPS location to a picture?

Tags: images, file-format, jpeg, geolocation, gpsd

Given a `.jpg` picture without associated GPS coordinates, how would you suggest to add custom coordinates to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`exiftool`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftool) command

e.g.:

```
exiftool -exif:gpslatitude="Put_the_GPS_coordinate_here" -exif:gpslatituderef=S your.jpg
```

Verify it:

```
exiftool -filename -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -T your.jpg
```